# SQL Update taking a long time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I am trying to update many rows (100 000+) in my database but it's taking a while (over 10 mins and still not finished). I'm wondering if this is intended behavior or is there something wrong in my code. To prevent the database from hanging while performing the update I've been told to update one row at a time, not sure if this is how it should be implemented.

I am updating images in my song table to be null if those songs were played in my playlist table

```
private function updateBlogSongs ($blog_id) {

        $db = Yii::app()->db;

        $affectedRows = 0;


        $sql = "SELECT *

                FROM `firstdatabase`.song s

                INNER JOIN `seconddatabase`.playlist p ON s.name LIKE p.song_name";


        $dataReader = $db->createCommand($sql)->query(); // Rows from the song table that were played in the given blog

        $row = $dataReader->read();


        while ($row != false) {

            $sql = "UPDATE `firstdatabase`.song s

                    SET s.image = NULL

                    WHERE s.song_id = " . $row['song_id'];


            $affectedRows += $db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

            

            $row = $dataReader->read();

        }


        return $affectedRows;

    }
```

Edit: after reading The Dog's comment I made some changes:
With 500 000 rows in the song table it takes about 10 minutes if I increase my batchSize to 10000 (was taking 8 hours with the code above). At 250 at the batch size it's taking about 50 minutes. I chose 250 because the query takes about 1 second to run, and it's taking 10+ seconds to run at 10000 batch size (constraint is 1 second). I would like to make it faster but not sure what else to change

```
$batchSize = 250;
        $lastSongID = 0;
        $rowIndex = 0;
        $affectedRows = 0;

        $sql = "SELECT max(song_id) FROM `firstdatabase`.song";
        $lastSongID = intval($db->createCommand($sql)->query()->read()['max(song_id)']);
        
        echo($lastSongID . ' songs in table.' . PHP_EOL);
        echo('Updating songs...' . PHP_EOL);

        while($rowIndex <= $lastSongID) {
            $startTime = microtime(true);

            
            $sql = "UPDATE `firstdatabase`.song
                    SET image = NULL
                    WHERE song_id in (
                        SELECT song_id
                        FROM (
                            SELECT song_id, name 
                            FROM `firstdatabase`.song 
                            WHERE song_id > " . $rowIndex . "
                            LIMIT " . $batchSize . "
                        ) s
                        INNER JOIN (
                            SELECT DISTINCT song_name 
                            FROM `seconddatabase`.playlist 
                        ) p ON s.name LIKE p.song_name
                        ORDER BY s.song_id ASC
                    )";

            $affectedRows += $db->createCommand($sql)->execute();


            $rowIndex += $batchSize;
            
            $endTime = microtime(true);
            $elapsedTime = round($endTime - $startTime, 2);
          
            
        }
```

Comment: could be that your can avoid the loop  and perform the updated  using a single query ...  try update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: 'LIKE' would only make sense if you were using a case-sensitive collation, and post lockdown beer says you're not.

Comment: The issue is that you are running SQL in a while loop.  Doing a database command inside of a while loop blows the run time into enormous amounts that you are seeing.  You HAVE to get this out of the while loop.  You can do this in one DB hit and not in a while loop.  I'll edit my response.

Comment: Consider your SQL, in your second code example, for each song in first database you are running a query to update 250 songs that are also in the second database playlist.  You do not need to do this in a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more a question for the SQL world instead of the PHP world but here's my recommendations:

Don't do this one row at a time in a while loop.  Make a more complex update statement that can do it all in one database hit.  Database commands are the slowest part of your php code, you want to limit the number of calls you do to the database.

When you are confident that you can get the operation done in one sql command, or even if you don't think it is possible then pull your code into a stored procedure in the database.  Having complex sql queries as stored procedures can help a lot with maintaining your code.

Make sure you have indexes on your tables.  You need to make sure your queries hit those indexes for best performance.

Here's an option for the single query:

```
update `firstdatabase`.song
set image = null
where song_id in (
    select s.song_id 
    from `firstdatabase`.song s
    INNER JOIN `seconddatabase`.playlist p 
        ON s.name LIKE p.song_name"
);
```

Obviously we don't have access to your database so you'll need to make changes where necessary but hopefully it can get you on the right track.

EDIT:
Try replacing your second code set with the following:

```
    $lastSongID = 0;
    $rowIndex = 0;
    $affectedRows = 0;
    
    $sql = "SELECT max(song_id) FROM `firstdatabase`.song";
    $lastSongID = intval($db->createCommand($sql)->query()->read()['max(song_id)']);
    
    echo($lastSongID . ' songs in table.' . PHP_EOL);
    echo('Updating songs...' . PHP_EOL);
    
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    $sql = "
        update `firstdatabase`.song
        set image = null
        where song_id in (
            select s.song_id 
            from `firstdatabase`.song s
            INNER JOIN `seconddatabase`.playlist p 
                ON s.name LIKE p.song_name"
        )";
    
    $affectedRows += $db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
        
    $endTime = microtime(true);
    $elapsedTime = round($endTime - $startTime, 2);
```

If it works, then let me know the time it takes to run, if it doesn't work, is it an issue with the SQL (again I can't see the tables so I'm guessing).

Comment: Appreciate the help, so far I made some changes that I edited in the description. I haven't been able to make it into one command, it's one query but I am running it with batches. I am also going to see if. I can pull the code into a stored procedure. It is still taking some time, not sure what else can be changed to increase the speed. Also the tables are indexed